# Direct communication between php script to client (Windows or Android)

Tags: php, android, sockets

I am thinking about a scenario where I want to send a data packet from my php service (based on certain behaviour) to a client (can be Android or Windows) connected to it.

A device which is connected to the internet is going to have an ip address.
So is it possible to send a packet (using socket or else) to this ip directly (without polling from client end) and can this data be read from the client.

Scenario is like this :

Client A  --------------Registers Own IP Address-----------------> Server

Client B  --------------Registers Own IP Address-----------------> Server

Events :

- Some changes occur in the database (say)
- Server detects the affected client (via some algo),say Client A
- Sends a packet to Client A

Client A  <--------------Send Data Packet----------------- Server

Is this at-all possible ?
If yes, how effective can this be ?

Please note that, Push notifications is not applicable in my situation.
I am looking for a live (realtime) data transmission system between client and server (both ways).

Any suggestion, help will be useful. Thanx

Comment: so you don't want to use a service like google cloud messaging??

Comment: No. I need to keep a realtime data-flow between the app and the server, and I cannot do it through gcm, as if I understand correctly, gcm will send push to the app and those push notifications are often delayed.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely possible to have persistent sockets open.

but I would say this would fail in a hosted environment. GoDaddy etc shuts that down. Been there done that.

I would highly recommend choosing a programming language like java (Whatever you are comfortable with).  It is only going to be 200 lines of code.

Comment: Ok, so if this fails in hosted environment(i am using godaddy), what alternatives do I have? I need this for android and windows phone apps, so it will be java and c# anyway.

Comment: Free tier aws ec2. Let me know if you need help with that route. Both environments can coexist or shove MX record to point to EC2 instance with apache on EC2

Comment: Alright. Definitely need some guidance there. Will get to see what this is tomorrow!

Comment: It keeps asking me for credit card information, and I don't have a credit card. So can I use AWS without having a credit card ?

Comment: I have used AWS for so long it is incredibly cheap. Some months my bill is 14 cents and i don't use the free tier. The credit card is probably so people don't abuse their service. It won't be charged at all inside the free tier. So i would cozy up to a friend/ mom

Comment: They know after the free year you will want to remain. Plus you may decide to have more powerful instances / services after a few days that are not covered in the free tier. Eitherway a static ip and 24/7.

Comment: I think they offer RDS in the free tier. That is hot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81476/discussion-between-priyabrata-and-drew-pierce).